# iframe design mode on cursor movement issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a iframe in design mode. When i start typing the text and the end of frame area comes, the scroll bar gets added but the cursor remains at the same place. Even though i am able to write more text. This happens only in chrome. it works in firefox. Here is the jsfiddle url

http://jsfiddle.net/rG9EV/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known Chrome bug](http://crbug.com/20844). Not much you can do but use another "online editor" technique.

Comment: When you say another online editor technique, can you shed some more light on it? Any links for samples